# перемножить значения ключей объектов

Tags: javascript, объекты, map-reduce

products - объект со свойствами "имя продукта":"цена за единицу"
order - объект со свойствами "имя продукта":"количество единиц".
Нужно перемножить одниковые значения ключей этих объектов,
необходимо использовать reduce

```
const products = {
  bread: 10,
  milk: 15,
  apples: 20,
  cheese: 30,
  chicken: 40
};

const orderA = {
  bread: 2,
  apples: 4,
  chicken: 1
};

const orderB = {
  bread: 1,
  milk: 2,
  cheese: 3
};

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderA)); // 140

console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderB)); // 130
```

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно перемножить одниковые значения ключей этих объектов, необходимо использовать `reduce`

если нужно - дак премножьте. необходимо - используйте.

```js
const products = {
  bread: 10,
  milk: 15,
  apples: 20,
  cheese: 30,
  chicken: 40
};

const orderA = {
  bread: 2,
  apples: 4,
  chicken: 1
};

const orderB = {
  bread: 1,
  milk: 2,
  cheese: 3
};

getTotalPrice = function(p, o){
  return Object.keys(p).reduce(function(acc, pkey){ 
        return o.hasOwnProperty(pkey) ?  acc + p[pkey] * o[pkey] : acc;
      }, 0); 
}

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderA)); // 140

console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderB)); // 130
```

Comment: спасибо ! то N-ное время сижу головой об стол бьюсь

Comment: куда разумней, конечно, сделать `return Object.keys(o).reduce( (acc, okey) => acc + p[okey] * o[okey])`, иначе лишняя проверка наличия ключа получается.

Answer (score 1):

Так как нужно найти сумму для `order*`, достаточно взять его поля и значения, и сворачивая полученный массив умножать значение, на значение соответствующего поля из products.

Для получения списка массивов (поле, значение), можно воспользоваться функцией [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Далее полученный массив можно свернуть воспользовавшись функцией [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

В итоге может получиться следующий код:

```js
const products = {
  bread: 10,
  milk: 15,
  apples: 20,
  cheese: 30,
  chicken: 40
};

const orderA = {
  bread: 2,
  apples: 4,
  chicken: 1
};

const orderB = {
  bread: 1,
  milk: 2,
  cheese: 3
};

getTotalPrice = function(products, order) {
  return Object.entries(order).reduce((acc, [product, count]) => acc + products[product] * count, 0);
}

// Вызовы функции для проверки
console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderA)); // 140

console.log(getTotalPrice(products, orderB)); // 130
```

Comment: хах, что-то я тупанул, ключи то и правда с другого объекта надо было брать (:

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант

```
function getTotalPrice(products, orderA) {
        return [products, orderA].reduce(function (previous, current) {
            if (!previous) {
                return  current;
            } else {
                var sum = 0;
                for (var key in current) {
                    if (previous[key]) {
                        sum += current[key] * previous[key];
                    }
                }
                return sum;
            }
        }, null);
    }
```

Comment: а что делает этот вариант?

Comment: возвращает orderA c измененными значениями

Comment: А должен возвращать _число_.

Comment: Извиняюсь, ТЗ недопонял. Не проблема переделать, но уже не актаульно, настолько я понял

Comment: Ответ все равно желательно поправить, неверные ответы обычно минусуются.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, исправил